# function that creates macro with macro name supplied as a parameter

Tags: clojure

I am trying to define a function that will create a macro and am running into problems when I try to dynamically supply the macro's name. Here's narrowed-down code that exemplifies the issue I am facing:

```
(defn create-times-macro [n]
  (defmacro thatManyTimes [a]
    `(* ~n ~a)))

(create-times-macro 2)

(thatManyTimes 3) ;; evals to 6
```

So far so good. Now say I want to supply the macro's name as a parameter:

```
(defn create-times-macro [macroName n]
  (defmacro macroName [a]
    `(* ~n ~a)))

(create-times-macro (symbol "multiplyBy") 3)
(multiplyBy 3) ;; fails with unable to resolve symbol multiplyBy
(create-times-macro "multiplyBy" 3)
(multiplyBy 3) ;; same failure
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it works:

```
=> (defmacro create-times-macro [macroName n]
     (let [the-name (symbol macroName)]
       `(defmacro ~the-name [a#]
          (* ~n a#))))
#'user/create-times-macro
=> (create-times-macro "hi" 3)
#'user/hi
=> (hi 4)
12
```

Comment: Are you sure it will work in a JAR ? See @Ankur answer below.

Comment: @Blacksad: This will work in JAR as it is macro creating a macro and not a function creating a macro.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you are confused about the use of macros.

- A macro which create a function - OK
- A macro which create another macro - OK
- A function creating a macro - Not OK (not common and usual).

All these points suggest the fact that macros are compile time thing where as functions are run-time thing. The usual direction is compile time to run-time where as the last point is about going from runtime to compile time.

Your first code example works in REPL but it won't work in a compiled JAR. In REPL you are in a compile-time->run-time->print->loop and becoz of the loop you sort of go back to compile->time from run-time and that is why the last point work in REPL. In compiled code you will only have, well, compiled code and there is only runtime world, unless you use `eval` in your code which can bring you back to compile time.... Wait my head hurts but I hope this make things clear :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need macro in this case. Functions are suitable in most cases and they have more abilities than macros. For example, if you create it as function

```
(defn create-times-fn [n]
  (fn [a]
    (* n a)))
```

you would get the same result

```
(def three-times (create-times-fn 3))

(three-times 2)
=> 6
```

or

```
(let [three-times (create-times-fn 3)]
  (three-times 2))
```

And you can pass it as argument to other functions

```
(map (create-times-fn 2) (range 5))
=> (0 2 4 6 8)
```

or return it as result or compose it with other functions. You lose all these things with macros.

Comment: This is a narrowed-down example. It is not the actual case I am facing. I just came up with a trivial example to demonstrate what I was trying to do.

Comment: Sorry about that. I just don't see purpose of macro which creates another macro.